# regexp to match AlphaNumeric with pattern

Tags: regex

**If alphanumeric all numbers can't be 9's**.

If lengh of the string 7 must be 1 alpha + 6 numeric.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the question.  You may wish to denote it with a "question mark."  Also, the criteria are confusing.  This would be much easier if you just counted the alphabetic and numeric characters in your string and checked that they meet the criteria.

Comment: you're looking for ie. A123456 but not A999999 ?

Comment: yes, exactly not A999999 any other combination is accepted

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:
For the first part

> if alphanumeric all numbers can't be 9's

and seeing that A999999 is not possible. It should not match this

```
[a-zA-Z]{1,2}[^9]{6}
```

but it should match this.

```
[a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{6}
```

Comment: I think \w: includes letters, hypens and apostrophes. Hypens and apostrophes are not alphabetical letters.